# Button that creates a <li> and adds user input on it

Tags: javascript, html

The exercise says that my button (like a submit) must use the information set by user in *input tag* and create an *li tag* with the text as content. It was my first JavaScript class, so I'm still not familiarised with the syntax.

This is my actual code. I used a `querySelector` with the `id` of my existing *ul tag*, and addEventListener to create an event for the click action. I can't remember how to properly create the new *li tag*, and don't know how to use the content as info for it.

```
let myElement = document.querySelector('#add-book');
myElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
if (e.target.classList == 'button-add') {
    let liElement = document.createElement('li');
    let content = document.appendChild(liElement);
    content.textContent();
    }
});
```

[image: the interface of the site]

I hope the button works properly, and show the element in the page by clicking the button (with the typed information).

Comment: Can you show HTML code, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```js
(function () {
  document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let input = document.querySelector('#text');
    let list = document.querySelector('#list'); 
    
    let item = document.createElement('li'); // create li node
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(input.value); // create text node
    
    item.appendChild(itemText); // append text node to li node
    list.appendChild(item); // append li node to list
    
    input.value = ""; // clear input
  });
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="text" type="text" />
  <button id="add">Add</button>
</div>

<ul id="list">
  <li>example item</li>
</ul>
```

But please, in the future, ask more specific questions. I don't even know what your problem is, because you don't provide all your code. Also the last sentence of your question is telling me nothing useful at all (.. "I hope the button works properly, and show the element in the page by clicking the button (with the typed information) " ..).

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm sorry for the lack of details, next time I'll do better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Oversimplified, but hey, it works:

```js
function AddLi(str)
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str))
    li.innerHTML += ' <button onclick="this.parentNode.remove()">-</button>';
    document.getElementById("out").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="userinput">
    <input type="button" value="Add LI" onclick="AddLi(userinput.value)">
</form> 
<span id="out"/>
```

Comment: I like the remove button you added in there, he should approve this answer! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
function addBook(book) {
  list.innerHTML += 
    `<li>${esc(book.value)} <button onclick="del(this)">Del</button></li>`;
  book.value = '';
}

function del(item) {
  item.parentNode.remove();
}

function esc(s) {
    return s.replace(/[&"<>]/g,c => 
      ({'&':"&amp;",'"':"&quot;",'<': "&lt;",'>':"&gt;"}[c]));
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>

<input id="data" type="text" />
<button onclick="addBook(data)">Add</button>
```

Comment: Try entering <foo> or something ;-)

Comment: Why not just use escape() ?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz the `escape('<foo>')` produce strange result: `"%3Cfoo%3E"`

Comment: You are right, didn't think about it, this function isn't for html escaping. Modified my answer to avoid it as well.

Comment: Why don't you just use the document.createElement element web API? It's the recommend way to add elements to the DOM.